# Error while using stanford core nlp

Tags: stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I m having problem in using the stanford nlp. i am having issues where I'm getting various errors when trying to use the Stanford Core NLP tools.I want to know the sentiment of the sentence passed. But I've not been able to get nlp tools to work when running the code from eclipse with the needed jars added to the classpath,

This is the code i want to execute.

```
import java.util.Properties;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.SentimentAnnotator;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.rnn.RNNCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.TypesafeMap.Key;

public class sentiment_demo {

    public static void sentiment_analysis(String line)
    {
        //Uses Stanford NLP sentimnet analysis
        //found in latest model released from stanford
        // ver 3.3.1
        //applies sentiment analysis to text 

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, parse, sentiment");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        int mainSentiment = 0;
        if (line != null && line.length() > 0) {
            int longest = 0;
            Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(line);
            for (CoreMap sentence : annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
                System.out.println(sentence);
                for (Tree token: sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.AnnotatedTree.class))
                {
                    //System.out.println(token);
                }
                Tree tree = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.AnnotatedTree.class);
                int sentiment = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(tree);
                System.out.println(sentiment);
                String partText = sentence.toString();
                //System.out.println(partText);
                if (partText.length() > longest) {
                    mainSentiment = sentiment;
                    longest = partText.length();
                }

            }
        }
        if(mainSentiment==2)
        {
            System.out.println("Average");
        }
        else if(mainSentiment>2)
        {
            System.out.println("Positive");
        }
        else if(mainSentiment<2)
        {
            System.out.println("Negative ");
        }

        if (mainSentiment == 2 || mainSentiment > 4 || mainSentiment < 0) {
            //return null;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        sentiment_analysis("Cristiano Ronaldo, is a Portuguese professional footballer who plays for Spanish club Real Madrid and the Portugal national team. He is a forward and serves as captain for Portugal.Often ranked as the best player in the world and rated by some in the sport as the greatest of all time");
    }
}
```

Here are the libraries i have set 
[image]

I m using eclipse mars. At first it was showing error for ejml library.but then i imported ejml jar file so that error was resolved but it gave rise to this errors now...

```
Adding annotator tokenize
Adding annotator ssplit
Adding annotator parse
Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ... done [1.6 sec].
Adding annotator sentiment
Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.stanford.nlp.neural.SimpleTensor
    at edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentModel.loadSerialized(SentimentModel.java:470)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.SentimentAnnotator.<init>(SentimentAnnotator.java:45)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$14.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:845)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:81)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:260)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:127)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:123)
    at sentiment_demo.sentiment_analysis(sentiment_demo.java:28)
    at sentiment_demo.main(sentiment_demo.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.stanford.nlp.neural.SimpleTensor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap.buildFromSorted(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap.buildFromSorted(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap.buildFromSorted(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap.buildFromSorted(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.readObjectFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:298)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentModel.loadSerialized(SentimentModel.java:466)
```

i m stuck at it.If someone have any idea of this then please do suggest,it will be of great help.I have searched other similar questions on stackoverflow but still not getting the solution to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using an old version of CoreNLP (3.3.0) alongside the new models. Try downloading the 3.6.0 code + models.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the problem was with different version used.some of the jar files like xom,ejml where missing.I fixed it by downloading the complete jar files from here stanford core NLP site with version 3.6.0. And one of the import statements was changed to

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.neural.rnn.RNNCoreAnnotations;
```

SentimentCoreAnnotations.AnnotatedTree.class needs to be changed to 
SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentAnnotatedTree.class

this changes have resolved my all errors.